# Matching New Line - Unix Shell

Tags: unix, shell

I am trying to see if a new line has been matched. The reason is that my script asks for the user's name. If they press enter, then a default name is used.

The problem is I cannot seem to check whether they have pressed enter, or used a name of their own. I have searched a lot on the net, and can't find a working answer. Here is what I have tried to implement:

```
if [ `expr match "$temp1" "\n"` != 0 ]
```

Very new to this. Thanks!

Comment: The key to all the answers presented is that the shell will strip off the newline. If the user just hit enter without typing any characters, the "temp1" variable will be empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
/bin/echo -n "Who? "
read name
if [ "x$name" != "x" ]
then
    echo "Hi $name"
else
    echo "Hi no-name"
fi
```

Comment: hey this seems to work! But I don't get why lol ... does the != just compare the first word or soemthing? I mean, doesn't "x" have the new line after x? Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to check if they have pressed enter. Just check the length of the string. Example:

```
if [ -z $input ]
then
    echo "No name was input. Setting default name"
    name=JOE
fi
```

Alternatively, you can use the following bash syntax to set a variable to a default value:

```
name=${input:-JOE}
```

This means that if the variable `input` is not set, `name` would be set to the default of "JOE".

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `read' bash builtin for this:

```
echo 'what is your name?'; read name; echo Hi ${name:='John'}
```

That will assign the name "John" as the default name if the user presses enter without entering any name.

I forgot to add that the feature that helps is is the default shell variable value assignment if it is not set ${name:='John'}.

Comment: The above response seems to work, and I understand it a bit better. If it doesnt work, I'll move to this one. Thanks so much!!